# How to check Windows license status in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, activation

I want my program to check if Windows 10 has been activated

I have the following code

```
 public static bool IsWindowsActivated()
    {
        bool activated = true;
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName + @"\root\cimv2");
        scope.Connect();

        SelectQuery searchQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_WindowsProductActivation");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcherObj = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, searchQuery);

        using (ManagementObjectCollection obj = searcherObj.Get())
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject o in obj)
            {
                activated = ((int)o["ActivationRequired"] == 0) ? true : false;
            }
        }
        return activated;
    }
```

when trying to use this code, the debugger complains `Invalid class`, which I have no idea what it is

what should I do to fix this? or is there any other way to check the license status of Windows?

Comment: where in the code do you get the `Invalid class` warning..?

Comment: @MethodMan in the `foreach` loop

Comment: What version of windows are you doing this on?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it's Windows 10

Comment: "Note  This class is not supported on platforms beyond Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 R2. On those platforms, it is recommended that you use the Software Licensing Classes instead."

Comment: @Luaan I checked MSDN, that class isn't for Windows 10...

Comment: To be fair, the note sounds very mild - something more indicative of "we left it in for backwards compatibility, don't use it", while the reality is that the management class simply doesn't exist anymore at all (this is more explicit in the sample code).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The WMI class [`Win32_WindowsProductActivation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394520(v=vs.85).aspx) is only supported on windows XP. For windows 10 you need to use [`SoftwareLicensingProduct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc534596(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
public static bool IsWindowsActivated()
{
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName + @"\root\cimv2");
    scope.Connect();

    SelectQuery searchQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE ApplicationID = '55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f' and LicenseStatus = 1");
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcherObj = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, searchQuery);

    using (ManagementObjectCollection obj = searcherObj.Get())
    {
        return obj.Count > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error, `Specified cast is not valid`, in `activated = ((int)o["LicenseStatus"] == 1) ? true : false;`

Comment: Refresh, I just updated with a much simpler check. make sure you update `SelectQuery` too, the query changed.